pyspark data frame transforn
i have a dataframe as follows:
f1     |f2
=========
test   | [{"f3": 1, "f4": "f4_1" }, {"f3": 2, "f4": "f4_2" }] 

f2 is a list of objects
i want to get a data frame like below:
f3|f4    | temp_col
=========================
1 |"f4_1"| {"f1": "test"}
2 |"f4_2"| {"f1": "test"}

temp_col is a name i provide.
how do i do that with pyspark?
i have tried using json_normalize by converting to pandas df but it didn't work.

what is the output of df.schema.simpleString()?

if you already loaded your json into a spark df , here is one way to do it:
result_df = df.withColumn("f2", explode(df.f2)).select(
    "f2.f3",
    "f2.f4",
    struct(col("f1")).alias("temp_col"),
)

output:
f3  f4  temp_col
1   f4_1    {"f1":"test"}
2   f4_2    {"f1":"test"}


great thanks. can you please explain this solution?

@xsaxsa sure , explode() returns a new row for each element in the given array then with select() you extract the columns inside the f2 column which is only one element like  {"f3": 1, "f4": "f4_1" } + struct() on f1 column to include column name and it's value as a dictionary and name it temp_col using alias()

You can use sc.parallelize for that
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from collections import OrderedDict

def convert_to_row(d: dict) -> Row:
    return Row(**OrderedDict(sorted(d.items())))

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('examples.com').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

data = {
 "f1": "test",
 "f2":[{"f3": 1, "f4": "f4_1" }, {"f3": 2, "f4": "f4_2" }]
}

df = sc.parallelize([dict(x, **{"temp_col": {"f1": data["f1"]}}) for x in data["f2"]]).map(convert_to_row).toDF()

df.show()


Great, thanks. But if the data frame is already loaded with the json? i updated the question
